# Core Data With iCloud Sync using NSPersistentCloudKitContainer

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I use NSPersistentCloudKitContainer to Sync Core Data with iCloud

But I found a problem, When I turned off iCloud Drive in my iPhone's iCloud Settings and reopened my app, all of my data disappeared. When I turned it back on, the data automatically synced back in.

According to my understanding, even if the iCloud Drive is turned off, the cloud synchronization function is not available, and the local data should still be saved for offline use. Why does such a problem occur?

this is my CoreDataStack code

```
let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: containerName)
    
    let containerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup)!
    
    let privateStoreURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent(privateStoreName)
    let privateDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: privateStoreURL)
    let privateOpt = NSPersistentCloudKitContainerOptions(containerIdentifier: identifier)
    privateDescription.cloudKitContainerOptions = privateOpt
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
    privateDescription.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
    privateDescription.configuration = "Cloud"
    
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [privateDescription]

    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    
    return container
```

This is My backgroundContext code which uses in-app logic

```
let newbackgroundContext = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    newbackgroundContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    newbackgroundContext.shouldDeleteInaccessibleFaults = true
    newbackgroundContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    return newbackgroundContext
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you find the solution?